# bash and arithmetic comparison: double quotes or not?

Tags: bash, comparison

when comparing two integers in bash, do we have to put double quotes ?
In the official document http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/comparison-ops.html I can read that double quotes should appear every time... But what is the differences in the following examples:

```
[ "$VAR" -eq "1" ]
[ $VAR -eq "1" ]
[ "$VAR" -eq 1 ]
[ $VAR -eq 1 ]
```

As I am curious, a took a look at Ubuntu init scripts in /etc/init.d and there are many usage of arithmetic comparison in it, at least [ "$VAR" -eq "1" ] and [ $VAR -eq 1 ] are used... but it seems no one really "knows" what is the official way to do it.

Thanks !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to quote `$VAR` if it could possibly be empty/unset (so you should probably always quote it).

If you don't quote it and it's empty, the statement results in:

```
[ -eq 1 ]
```

which is a syntax error. Quoting the `1` doesn't gain anything though.

(Also look at [bash conditional expressions](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/ccmd/conditional_expression) (things with `[[ ... ]]`), a more "modern" version of the test command that has less quirks.)

Comment: As far as I know `[` invokes the test-command, while `[[` is a Bash-builtin...so it might not be an option.

Comment: I know, that's why it's added as a note (and that's also why it doesn't have the same quirks). Question is tagged `bash` though, so I believe it's relevant.

Comment: `[` is a bash builtin -- see `type \[`

Comment: Quoting an undefined variable still throws an error (integer expression expected) since its trying to compare an empty string with an integer...

Answer (score 3):

If you want to arithmetic comparison, use the arithmetic conditional construct (documented [here](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Conditional-Constructs)):

```
(( VAR == 1 ))
```

Comment: It's true that I learned (about ten years ago) to handle arithmetics comparison with "[" bash bultin , so it's not easy to let it go ^^

Comment: Should be the accepted answer.

Comment: Doesn't answer if and when to use double quotes or not.